# if a TCP packet got partially acknowledged, how will the retransmission mechanism react?

Tags: networking, tcp

if a tcp client send  a packet, with sequence number from 10000 to 20000, to a tcp server.
the tcp will respond with an ACK with seq_ack 20001.

if I intercept the TCP packet from the client, and split the packet into 2 tcp segments, one with seq from 10000 to 15000, and the other with seq from 15001 to 20000. And then these 2 TCP segments are sent to the TCP server. Assume that the second segment is lost in the path.
The TCP server will respond an ACK with seq_ack 15001.

Now since the TCP client send a integral packet with seq 10000 to 20000, but it gets an ACK with 15001, from the client's point of view, this is weird. How will it react? In theory, the client should retransmit the bytes from seq 15001 to 20000, namely, the client will transmit new packets from seq 15001. But how about the practice, in TCP stack implementation, is it the same as in the theory?

I think in the TCP send buffer, when a tcp segment is sent, the segment still stays there until the ACK. When the ACK come, these bytes for the segment are cleared from the buffer.
There is a pointer in the send buffer, when an ACK come, the pointer points to the location where the ack_seq corresponds to. The bytes that are below the ack_seq are cleared. In this way, the whole segment needn't be retransmitted?

Answer (score 8):

This is called [selective acknowledgement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Selective_acknowledgments), and is already included in the TCP specification defined in [RFC 2018](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2018).  This would allow the client to indeed resend just bytes 15001 to 20000 (since they are in different packets/segments *if* you had split them as you say), but more interestingly, it even allows out-of-order acknowledgements.

From RFC 2018:

> When receiving an ACK containing a SACK option, the data sender SHOULD record the selective acknowledgment for future reference.  The data sender is assumed to have a retransmission queue that contains the segments that have been transmitted but not yet acknowledged, in sequence-number order.

Supporting `SACK` is **not** required by the TCP specification.  If either the client *or* the server did not support selective acknowledgement, indeed all of the bytes 10000 to 20000 would have to be retransmitted.

> In TCP stack implementation, is it the same as in the theory?

Usually `SACK` *is* supported, as the performance, efficiency, and latency gains are significant - especially in a network like the internet.

Indeed however, these assumptions should hold true even if you manually manipulate the packets as you stated.  As per [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793), at minimum, the entire data window will have to be retransmitted, but the reciever *does* know that the recieved data is at least *valid*.  For implementation details, [Section 3.3 - Sequence Numbers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.3) from RFC 793.

For an outline of the entire process both with and without selective acknowledge support, see [this article](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/17/tcp-selective-acknowledgments-sack/) (which includes some very useful diagrams).

Comment: it is a bit strange to me, because TCP is stream-based, byte-oriented protocol. Why should it retransmit the whole segment? It seems to me that TCP without SAKC is segment-oriented stream protocol, but TCP with Sack is real byte-oriented. I think the RFC doesn't specifically elaborate on this.

Comment: how TCP stack manage its send buffer, is it the same as what I wrote in the updated question.

Comment: @misteryes [this article](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/17/tcp-selective-acknowledgments-sack/) outlines the process (with some great diagrams, too!).

Comment: In the link you recommended, it seems that the author still discuss the problem in a segment-oriented way, not in real byte-oriented way. Isn't it?

Comment: I knew SACK before I post this question. At the very beginning I don't think SACK has something to do with this question. In my opinion, if TCP is not byte-oriented but segment-oriented, then SACK should also be the same. The difference between SACK-enabled and SACK-disabled is that with SACK, TCP allows a sequence hole in ack_seq. But I thought the sequence hole corresponds to a segment. while according to your saying, the hole can be half/part of a segment.

Comment: @misteryes the byte measures were just to show an example using the numbers *you* provided - indeed TCP is packet/segment based.  Of course if I sent all of those bytes in a single packet, regardless of the presence of SACK support, every byte in that packet will have to be resent.  Data is verified in TCP via a checksum in all of the packet headers, so if the checksum did not match, one would have to discard the entire packet.

Comment: if I want to intercept and divide the segment into 2 segments, I will of course make the checksum correct for each new segment. so checksum is not an issue. The only issue is TCP should be byte oriented, but according to your saying, TCP is segment-oriented

Comment: @misteryes I'm not sure what you mean by that - TCP is a *packet* or *segment* switched networking protocol, even in cases where packets are split up (by, for example, a gateway).  From [RFC 793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt): `The TCP packages the data from these buffers into segments and calls on the internet module to transmit each segment to the destination TCP. [...]  A destination internet module unwraps the segment from the datagram (after reassembling the datagram, if necessary) and passes it to the destination TCP.`

Comment: it seems I havn't made everything clear. for example, I have a tcp sender, a tcp receiver, and in between I have a middle node. When the tcp sender sends a TCP packet withe seq 10000 to 20000. The middle node intercept it, split it into 2 TCP packet(with correct checksum), one with seq from 10000 to 15000, the other with 15000 to 20000. and then the middle node sends these 2 packets to the tcp receiver.

Comment: let me give another example, if you are the sender, you send me a packet with seq 10000 to 20000, I'm a receiver(I manipulate the TCP receiver so it doesn't send ACK 20001), I send you an ACK 15001. If you are byte-oriented, you should send from 15001. But if you are segment-oriented, you should send from 10000. But according to RFC, TCP is byte-oriented, the sender shouldn't care whether segment is lost or not, the sender only cares which bytes are lost.

Comment: @misteryes I don't know what you mean when you say "TCP is byte-oriented" since data is only transmitted in TCP segments/packets.  If *any* of the bytes in a segment are lost, the checksum of that segment would then be invalid, and **the entire segment** must be resent.  You have no way of validating individual bits/bytes in a TCP segment/packet, only all of them at once.

Comment: I can intercept the TCP packet, divided into 2 segments, carefully compute the checksum for each segments. and then send them to the tcp receiver

Comment: @misteryes Yes, this is infact what some routers/gateways will to in certain cases.  This refers to the process of [IP fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation).

Comment: haha, That is not IP fragmentation. For IP fragmentation, the kernel will not deliver the whole TCP segment into TCP stack unless all fragments are received. In my case, I will divide the TCP packet into 2 IP packets and computer checksum for both IP and TCP header.

Comment: you can  have a look at this article: TCP segmentation offload: http://sandilands.info/sgordon/segmentation-offloading-with-wireshark-and-ethtool

Comment: If a sender transmits a packet with sequence numbers 1000 to 1099, and doesn't receive an ack before it has 200 more bytes to send, it may proceed to transmit a packet with sequence numbers 1000 to 1199.  At that point, the sender has no real reason to care that it ever sent a packet with sequence numbers 1000 to 1099; from its perspective, what matters is that there are 200 bytes outstanding with the range 1000-1199.  If it gets an ack 1100, it should figure there are 100 bytes outstanding 1100-1199, regardless of whether it had sent a packet ending at 1099.

Answer (score 3):

Segment sizes can (and do) change over the lifetime of a connection. Luckily, TCP has no need to record the segment size that individual packets were sent with previously. Therefore, it will do the following:

1. Whenever an ACK arrives, advance the pointer to the first unacknowledged byte accordingly and discard any now-unneeded buffer.
2. When the need arises for retransmission (Fast Retransmit or Timeout; **NOT** immediately after the receipt of the first ACK!), it will resend in the *currently valid segment size* starting from the pointer to the first unacknowledged byte.

Both operations are done independently of the segment size these bytes were originally sent in. So the theory should match most implementations.

Let me give some background to explain:

Does TCP use bytes or segments? To the application, TCP exposes a byte stream interface. Also, all the header fields and internal variables are in bytes. However, to transmit information, TCP chunks them up in segments, as sending bytes one-by-one would be pretty wasteful :-). Using byte counters everywhere has the advantage that the segment size does not need to remain constant over the lifetime of the connection:

- Options are being introduced, e.g. piggybacking a SACK on a retransmit (real implementations will  encounter this rarely, if at all)
- The Path MTU changes, e.g. one link along the path changes to a lower MTU or the bottleneck MTU link is raised. This happens when tunnels are established (VPN, PPPoE) or the routing protocol selects a different-MTU link. This happens in IPv4 with Don't Fragment set (true for most modern TCPs); always in TCPv6).

BTW: SACK is not the answer here, as the receiver will (typically) only use SACK if it recognizes a [hole in the byte stream](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2018#section-4) (i.e., if a packet got lost but a following packet arrived).